# Errors when booting Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.7.1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, amd-graphics, amd

I have a Ryzen 5 3500U laptop and I know the drivers aren't there yet with linux but I'd like to know if any of you have experienced/solved the following errors when starting up / shutting down the pc.

```
[0.424362] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC10.GPP2.BCM5] AE_NOT_FOUND (20200326/dswload2-162)

[0.424383] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20200326/psobject-220)

[0.777326] Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed

[0.790421] pci 0000:00:00.2: AMD-Vi: Unable to read/write to IOMMU perf counter.
```

Comment: Are these causing problems or are you just seeing them on the screen without negative consequences?

Comment: I've had an instance of not being able to boot and have had problem with booting without iommu=soft on other kernels so I got a bit scared by this appearing on the new kernel

Answer (score 2):

Most of these messages, including the first, second, and fourth, are harmless.  The first two probably indicate some sort of bug in your firmware, and it's well known (at least by the Linux authors) that firmware tends to be poorly written.

If you're booting with `iommu=soft`, then the last message is also normal and expected.  It's diagnostic and probably not something to worry about.

The third message is potentially more worrying, but if your system boots, then you're probably okay.  That message indicates that the initramfs, which is a small file system that contains the necessary files and kernel modules to boot your system, may be corrupt.  However, since the system boots, it's probably [this Ubuntu issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1835660), which is reported to be cosmetic.

So none of these are things to worry about.  The Linux kernel produces lots of diagnostic messages and reports a lot of things to the screen that other OSes will either ignore or hide in the logs.  Unless you're seeing a particular problem or you know the message indicates a problem (like a disk error), then things are probably fine.

Comment: I am not booting with iommu=soft at the moment though, and I don't have any of these messages when booting to kernel 5.4, maybe 5.7 is still unstable?

Comment: None of these messages are especially concerning to me, and I've been using Linux for well over a decade.  Unless you're seeing actual problems, just ignore them.  They almost certainly don't indicate a problem you need to act on.